# give legend to each point using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create an id to each fruit (1-20) in regards to the date of measure at different plots and differentiate the specific fruit at the specific date by size, so I can track the specific fruit along the time (in order to see the specific fruit along the time)

I used this code:

```
ggplot(pink_lady_fruit_mm_by_date_plot_year, aes(x= date, y= Fruit))+
    geom_jitter(aes(color= Size), na.rm = TRUE)+
    facet_wrap(~plot)
```

It's working well but I cannot track the specific fruit (1-20).
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post data? Edit the question with the output of `dput(head(pink_lady_fruit_mm_by_date_plot_year, 30))`, please.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of tracking your fruit is using something similary to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901459/10782538) and adding colours to each group.
I'll use `mtcars` as an example dataset here.

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, col = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  #wrap around.. something
  facet_wrap(~am) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('6' = 'blue', '4' = 'green', '8' = 'yellow'))
```

so for your specific example we could do something like (untested):

```
col <- 1:length(pink_lady_fruit_mm_by_date_plot_year$Fruit)
names(col) <- levels(factor(pink_lady_fruit_mm_by_date_plot_year$Fruit))
ggplot(pink_lady_fruit_mm_by_date_plot_year, aes(x = date, y = Fruit, col = factor(Fruit))) +
    geom_jitter(aes(color= Size), na.rm = TRUE) +
    facet_wrap(~plot) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = col)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Oliver, it give me an error says: continuous value supplied to discrete scale, do you know how it is possible to solve it?

Comment: Ah, yes i was a bit fast there. The reason this error pops up, is that  `scale_colour_manual` expects `col = ...` to be a discrete scale variable (eg. a `factor(...)`). Similar to the first example `col = factor(cyl)` it should've been `col = factor(Fruit)`. I'll update my answer to make this clear. :-)