# how to add legends ggplot in charts facet_warp() in R?

Tags: r

I maked the chart in R using gglopt() and facet_warp(), but do not appear legends of geom_lines() and stat_smooth().

my code exemple is:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp)) + 
      geom_line(color="red")+
      facet_wrap(~cyl)+
      stat_smooth()+
      guides()
```

[image]

how to add legends in the chart final?

Comment: What is the color supposed to represent?

Comment: @Zaw red= geom_line() and blue = stat_smooth()

Comment: This question had already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901253/adding-a-legend-to-a-ggplot-with-facet-wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the labels for color aesthetics for each plot and link the color using named vectors in `values` parameter of `scale_color_manual()`.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = "line.color")) +
  stat_smooth(aes(color = "smooth.color")) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("line.color" = "red", "smooth.color" = "blue"))
```

[image]